# nth-child selector doesn't work in media query

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I have a project built with react and reactstrap (bootstrap 4 components). When I add the code

```
    .col:nth-child(3) {
    order: -1 !important;
}
```

it work great, but when I try to add in a media query it doesn't work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700) {
.col:nth-child(3) {
    order: -1 !important;
    max-width: 700px
}}
```

what is going on here??

it is part of a nav built with reactStrap.

```
<Nav className='nav'>
    <Col>
      <Link to='/product'>
        <NavItem className='nav-item'>Product</NavItem>
      </Link>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <Link to='/brand'>
        <NavItem className='nav-item'>Brands</NavItem>
      </Link>
    </Col>
    <Col className='nav-column'>
      <Link to='/'>
        <NavItem className='nav-item nav-title'>
          <h1 className='title'>
            Makeup <span className='bomb'>Bomb</span>
          </h1>
        </NavItem>
      </Link>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <Link to='/update'>
        <NavItem className='nav-item'>Update</NavItem>
      </Link>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <Link to='/about'>
        <NavItem className='nav-item'>About</NavItem>
      </Link>
    </Col>
  </Nav>
```

Comment: try `max-width: 700px` you should specify the pixel for that size.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
   .col:nth-child(3) {
     order: -1 !important;
   }
}
```

Try this instead, you haven't used PX and did not close the bracket

Answer (score 0):

Here you go - Move screen resolution over `700px` to see the color change.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/dztc80L1/22/) for screen visualization.

```css
Nav :nth-child(1) {
  order: -1 !important;
  color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  Nav :nth-child(1) {
    order: -1 !important;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<Nav className='nav'>
  <Col class="col">
  <Link to='/product'>
  <NavItem className='nav-item'>Product</NavItem>
  </Link>
  </Col>

  <Col class="col">
  <Link to='/brand'>
  <NavItem className='nav-item'>Brands</NavItem>
  </Link>
  </Col>

  <Col className='nav-column'>
  <Link to='/'>
  <NavItem className='nav-item nav-title'>
    <h1 className='title'>
      Makeup <span className='bomb'>Bomb</span>
    </h1>
  </NavItem>
  </Link>
  </Col>

  <Col class="col">
  <Link to='/update'>
  <NavItem className='nav-item'>Update</NavItem>
  </Link>
  </Col>

  <Col class="col">
  <Link to='/about'>
  <NavItem className='nav-item'>About</NavItem>
  </Link>
  </Col>
</Nav>
```

Comment: Its strange because it works in the fiddle but it isn't working in my project. Could it be that because I am using reactstrap something is interfering with the media query?

Comment: In that case you need to look into the precedence, the last set of css code will take precedence over the other! I assume there is a conflict between elements in your css code. There is no different css for react bootstrap. You can try adding this code at the last and try once.

Comment: but shouldnt !important override it? the media query is the last thing on the stylesheet for the component

Comment: No, even if you have added `!important` in the beginning and at the last you have same css class defined with different value then it executes that, you can check doing inspect element and see why it isn't working, I am pretty much sure it is very small mistake. I just saw one article related to this add saying to add this under `<head>` you can try this as well, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

Comment: @Ren any progress?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I decided to change the class .col to an id. This works.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #col:nth-child(3) {
        order: -1 !important;

    }
}
```